# Removing elements from the end of a vector in C++ using iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, time-complexity, invalidation

I would like to remove elements from a vector in reverse order, starting from the last element.  As far as I know, the easiest way to do this with an iterator is:

```
std::vector<int> data = ...
std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
for(iter = data.end() - 1; iter != data.begin() - 1; iter--) {
    data.erase(iter);
}
```

My question is, will each of these erase() calls be O(1), since we are removing at the end, even though the general complexity for removal is O(n)?  Also, is this code "safe" assuming the vector has at least 1 element?

Comment: How about `data.erase(data.rbegin(), data.rend())`?

Comment: What is your actual problem? It doesn't matter for vector of ints the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your algorithm has UB.
If it didn't it would have O(n).
Changing the body to this would remove the UB: `iter = data.erase(iter);`
Why? Because `vector.erase()` behaves like this:

- Effects: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase.
- Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements
  erased, but the move assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of
  elements in the vector after the erased elements.

If you rewrite the loop like this, it will even work for empty container:

```
for(auto it = data.end(); it!=data.begin(); it = data.erase(it-1)) /**/;
```

It is equal to:

```
std::remove_if(data.rbegin(), data.rend(), [](data::reference x){return true;});
```

Anyway, using `data.clear()`, `data.resize(0)` or swapping with a temporary empty vector would most likely be faster.

Comment: What if I want to "skip over" some of the elements based on a condition during iteration?  I realize this would no longer be an O(n) algorithm, but could I simply use `if(condition) it = data.erase(it-1); else it--` and keep the iterator position consistent?

Comment: yes, though that makes your algorithm quadratic: `O(n²)`. You would be better off calling `std::remove_if()` with a reverse iterator. That is guaranteed `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks!  remove_if looks like a much cleaner way to do what I want to do--but is there a way to retrieve which items were removed by remove_if for reference?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to the current element in the predicate. Even copy it somewhere else for safekeeping.

Comment: @donnyton No, they are overwritten. Do you actually want to split the vector?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you really *need* to delete them in reverse order, you're better off simply calling `data.clear()`.

Otherwise, no, it's not "safe": forming `data.begin() - 1` is undefined, and decrementing `iter` after you called `.erase` on it is also undefined. [Deduplicator has posted a good fix for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23037341/560648)

Answer (score 0):

Kinda. Complexity of std::vector erase() is

> Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions) plus the number of elements after the last element deleted (moving).

Based on this source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

As you are removing only one element and its the last one, its linear with N=1 which can be interpreted as O(1) constantish.